# Basic Authentication in play framework

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework

How to implement Basic Authentication for web sockets  using play framework.

I am creating a web socket using play framework.
I would like to do basic authentication and send 401 if authentication fails.
Below is my code and i am not able to send "{code=401, message=unauthorized access}" as response

```
def ChatServer(): WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    if (Util.doBasicAuthentication(request.headers)) {
      ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
        ChatActor.props(out)
      }
    } else throw new RuntimeException("Unauthorized Access")
  }
```

Whenever authentication fails, i am not able to send the response back as "unauthorized access" instead i am ending up with exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaWebSockets#Rejecting-a-WebSocket), use [`WebSocket.acceptOrResult`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/WebSocket$.html#acceptOrResult[In,Out](f:play.api.mvc.RequestHeader=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[Either[play.api.mvc.Result,akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[In,Out,_]]])(implicittransformer:play.api.mvc.WebSocket.MessageFlowTransformer[In,Out]):play.api.mvc.WebSocket):

```
def socket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] { request =>
  Future.successful {
    if (Util.doBasicAuthentication(request.headers)) {
      Right(ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
        ChatActor.props(out)
      })
    } else {
      Left(Unauthorized)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jeffry Chung Thanks. it worked but is there any way to send string as response ?

Comment: Yes, just send the string as argumnet, like `Unauthorized("msg")`, be aware that this flow still accepts the web socket connection which is ended right away.